# Python Dictionary with Tuple as Values. Access the last index of the tuple

Tags: list, python-3.x, dictionary, indexing, tuples

Lets say I have a dictionary that looks like this:
(all the tuples have same length)

```
dict_new = {1:(1,2,"work"), 2:(3,4,"sleep")}
```

How do I access the last index of key key 1 (in this case its "work"):

Comment: `dict_new[1][-1]` will give you the value with key `1`, then get you the item at index `-1` which is the last index

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's always three items, you can refer to it directly by index:

```
dict_new[1][2]
```

If you want the last one regardless of tuple length, use negative indexing:

```
dict_new[1][-1]
```

However, it looks like your tuples are data containers of some sort; I would highly suggest creating a [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) class for that, something like:

```
from collections import namedtuple

# define your data type and the fields it contains:
Entry = namedtuple('Entry', ['start', 'end', 'activity'])

# now add Entry objects instead of bare tuples:
dict_new = {1: Entry(1, 2, "work"), 2: Entry(3, 4, "sleep")}
```

Then you can access it via:

```
dict_new[1].activity  # gives you "work"
```